# what is the best way to check if a string exists in another?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: string contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/javascript-string-contains)

I'm looking for an algorithm to check if a string exists in another.

For example:

```
'Hello, my name is jonh LOL.'.contains('Hello, my name is jonh'); //true
'LOL. Hello, my name is jonh'.contains('Hello, my name is jonh'); //true
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here a benchmark for the most common ways to check if a string is in a string: http://jsben.ch/#/o6KmH

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```
'Hello, my name is jonh LOL.'.indexOf('Hello, my name is jonh') > -1; //true
'LOL. Hello, my name is jonh'.indexOf('Hello, my name is jonh') > -1; //true
```

You can also extend `String.prototype` to have a `contains` function:

```
String.prototype.contains = function(substr) {
  return this.indexOf(substr) > -1;
}
'Hello, my name is jonh LOL.'.contains('Hello, my name is jonh'); //true
'LOL. Hello, my name is jonh'.contains('Hello, my name is jonh'); //true
```

Comment: further to this answer, you could create `function contains(haystack, needle) { return haystack.indexOf(needle) > -1; }` Or even create one on the String prototype

Comment: @Jonathan I added a `String.prototype` function.

Answer (score 1):

As Digital pointed out the `indexOf` method is the way to check.  If you want a more declarative name like `contains` then you can add it to the `String` prototype.

```
String.prototype.contains = function(toCheck) {
  return this.indexOf(toCheck) >= 0;
}
```

After that your original code sample will work as written

Answer (score 1):

How about going to obscurity:

```
!!~'Hello, my name is jonh LOL.'.indexOf('Hello, my name is jonh'); //true
if(~'LOL. Hello, my name is jonh'.indexOf('Hello, my name is jonh'))
    alert(true);
```

Using Bitwise NOT and to boolean NOTs to convert it to a boolean than convert it back.

Comment: although this works, `val > -1` is fewer operations

Comment: @zzzzBov, technically the !! Is unnecesary. So just the tilde would work.

Comment: ...depending on how strictly you need a boolean value. I agree, `~` will output the correct falsey state.

Answer (score 0):

I would suppose that using pre-compiled Perl-based regular expression would be pretty efficient.

```
RegEx rx = new Regex('Hello, my name is jonh', RegexOptions.Compiled);
rx.IsMatch('Hello, my name is jonh LOL.'); // true
```

Comment: I'm using JavaScript, but thanks :P

Comment: Even better:

`var regex = /Hello, my name is jonh/;
regex.test("Hello, my name is jonh LOL."); // true`

Answer (score 0):

another option could be to match a regular expression by using match(): http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp.

```
> var foo = "foo";
> console.log(foo.match(/bar/));
null
> console.log(foo.match(/foo/));
[ 'foo', index: 0, input: 'foo' ]
```